# How to read factor vs. factor plots?

Tags: pca, plotting

How to read factor vs. factor plots?

Particularly, what do negative values mean? Also, why is it possible for features to have negative effect on the factors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret the loading values of a pca?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14300/how-to-interpret-the-loading-values-of-a-pca)